# Wordpress one time access to password protected page

Tags: wordpress, password-protection, one-time-password, totp

I am creating a wordpress page which is password protected. It holds a form which needs to be submitted after a timed period of 3h. After that period the user should be logged out, no matter wether he completed the form or not. He should not be able to log in again.

As of now I achieved to set a timer after which the content of the page disappears. Now I need a tool that prevents a particular user to log back in and resubmit the form. Users do not get registered on my site. I want to email them a password for the protected page.

I can't simply change the password after login because as of now the page is protected by one password that every potential user needs to use.

To me the easiest way to avoid relogin seems to be the issuing of one time passwords for this particular page, so upon request every user gets his own OTP.

I am looking for a plugin which generates a list of OTPs for a specific wp page. 
Easy solutions are greatly appreciated, since I am not seasoned at coding!

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP. Everybody starts somewhere...

Comment: I would probably set a token in a postmeta field and bind that to a transient (timer) on first call ... Then you just append the token as parameter to the url ... If needed there can be multiple tokens (accesses) for one page

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not tested):

```
$token = $_GET[ 'token' ];

if( is_numeric( $token ) AND metadata_exists( 'post', get_the_ID(), 'token_' . $token ) ):


    if( empty( get_metadata( 'post', get_the_ID(), 'token_' . $token, true ) ) )
        update_metadata( 'post', get_the_ID(), 'token_' . $token, time() + ( HOUR_IN_SECONDS * 3 );


    if( $stamp = get_metadata( 'post', get_the_ID(), 'token_' . $token, true ) < time() ):

        echo 'Here goes your form';

        echo 'You have ' . $stamp - time() . ' seconds.';

    else:

        echo 'nope';

        delete_metadata( 'post', get_the_ID(), 'token_' . $token )

    endif;

else:

    echo 'nope';

endif;
```

So you just have to create a empty postmeta field like `token_98751328475` and share the url like `example.com/myformpage?token=98751328475`.

I would probably create a confirmation page to start the timer so that it doesn't start on first call.